# Verify Stripe web-hook manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to manually verify web-hook:

```
const stripeSecret = createHmac('sha256', STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET)
        .update(event.body)
        .digest('hex');

if(stripeSecret !== keyFromHeader) {
  throw err();
}
```

But it is not matched with Stripe secret key which is received in header.
Here is event data which I am also trying to use in Stripe API (it also fails):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's not event.body you should hash According to the documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#verify-manually
) its a concatenation of :

- The timestamp (as a string)
- The character .
- The actual JSON payload (i.e., the request body) => JSON.stringify(req.body)

you will need to parse this to get the timestamp (the xxxxx in the "t=xxxxx" part)

```
const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
```

if you give me a sample stripe signature header i can try a code sample.

Comment: why I need timestamp? and where to use it?

Comment: the doc says so. its what stripe decided

Comment: I doesn't helps:
const stripeSecret = createHmac('sha256', STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET)
        .update(timestamp+'.'+event.body)
        .digest('hex');

Comment: I can't see the code for timestamp extraction. So I must believe you parsed the header correctly. Is event.body the full unmodified request body your route received as Json string ? Are you also sure it's not an object ?

Comment: yes, I've even tried to use native stripe API:
stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(JSON.stringify(event.body), signature, STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET); But it also fails:
 "No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?

Answer (score 0):

`event.body` might not be enough — it's very common in Node server environments for that to be a "parsed" version of the incoming request body, and instead you need to make sure to access the actual raw JSON string in the body — that's what Stripe's signature is computed against. It can be a little tricky!

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/tree/master/examples/webhook-signing
(and many examples contributed for various frameworks at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/341 )

Also, is there a specific reason to do this manually and not just use Stripe's Node library? :)

Comment: I've tried to use next check:
stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
But it fails also with error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Comment: It's **almost certainly** the problem I describe in my answer then, I'd suggest checking those links. You need to first get the exact, raw HTTP POST body since that's what the signature is verified against, that's the first step. It has to match exactly what you see on your Stripe dashboard, including whitespace and the ordering of the JSON keys!

Comment: I've tried JSON.stringify(event.body) but result the same

Comment: `JSON.stringify(event.body)` is not right and would never work — as the error message says, you need the _raw_ body per the links above! Touching it in any way(like running it through `strinfigy` like that) will modify it.